# Pick up your phone! It's vibrating!

Tags: code-golf, string

You just recently got a new phone, but you don't quite like the way it vibrates, you've decided you want to create your own vibration patterns. So, you've written a program where you used the keywords `long`, `short` and `pause` to make your phone vibrate according to these keywords.

### Task

Create a small program that accepts a string of `long`, `short`, and `pause` and outputs another string representing the phonetic sound of a phone vibrating; `Rrrr - Rr`

`long` sounds are `Rrrr`
`short` sounds are `Rr`
(Casing matters)
`pause` is a dash `-`
all sounds are delimited by dash with surrounding spaces `' - '`

### Test Cases

input:   `long long short long short`

output: `Rrrr - Rrrr - Rr - Rrrr - Rr`

input:   `long long long short short short`

output: `Rrrr - Rrrr - Rrrr - Rr - Rr - Rr`

input:   `short short short pause short short short`

output: `Rr - Rr - Rr - - - Rr - Rr - Rr`

input:   `long short short long long pause short short`

output: `Rrrr - Rr - Rr - Rrrr - Rrrr - - - Rr - Rr`

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with the fewest bytes winning.

Comment: Which exactly "sounds" can be used? For example, what about `Mmm` and `M`?

Comment: "Any sound, as long as it sounds like a vibrating phone, can be used"

Comment: Isn't that a subjective criterion? I would like to use empty string, it sounds like a vibrating phone to me.

Comment: I realize now that one could totally use no characters. Alright, I'll fix my question.

Comment: Your "sounds like" rule is much too vague. I'd suggest just requiring exact strings. Code golf requires precise criteria so we can optimize code without having argument on whether an improvement is valid.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of words?

Comment: Do we have to delimit the sounds with a `-`? This is the case in your example, but is not specified anywhere.

Comment: About to post a C solution, removing the `-` delimiter would save me so many bytes...

Comment: The examples all use a capital lower followed by copies of a lowercased letter. Is this a rule?

Comment: What needs to be done before this can be reopened: 1) Specify the *exact* strings (or sets of strings) we must use, including case limitations, 2) Clarify whether input and/or output can be an array either of words or arrays of characters, 3) Specify the exact separator that must be used when outputting as a string.

Comment: Without all of the above a (quick) Japt port of muddyfish's Pyke solution could be anywhere between 12 and 24 bytes long.

Comment: Half of the answers are now invalid due to the changes. I would have allowed all 2 or 4 letter strings.

Comment: And there is still the problem of the delimiter. Must it be `-` as stated by the examples, or can we use whatever delimiter is best for our language of choice?

Comment: You have yet to clarify points 2 & 3 above, as well as the second part of point 1 (casing).

Comment: The examples include spaces but the description does not (it implies `Rrrr-Rr---Rr-Rrrr` is a valid output given the input `long short pause short long` for example). Are the spaces mandatory or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
cFh.o6.&\R*\-|l4)J" -
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=63+46+68+EF+36+A6+5C+52+2A+5C+2D+7C+6C+34+29+4A+22+20+2D+20&input=long+pause+short&warnings=1&hex=1)

```
c                      -  split(input, " ")
 Fh.o6.&\R*\-|l4)      -  for i in ^:
  h                    -        ^[0]
   .o                  -       ord(^)
     6.&               -      ^ & 6
        \R*            -     ^
           \-|         -    ^ or "-"
              l4       -   ^.title()
                 J" -  - " - ".join(^)
```

The crux of this answer is the transformation of `["long", "short", "pause"]` into `[4, 2, 0]`. It gets the code point of the first letter of each word and `AND`s it with 6. By lucky coincidence it transforms to the values we're looking for. (I searched through quite a few other longer solutions before finding this one). Once that's done, we can further transform that list of ints into `["RRRR", "RR", ""]` by multiplying our int by `"R"` which then turns into `["RRRR", "RR", "-"]` and finally title casing it to get `["Rrrr", "Rr", "-"]`. We then join the resulting list by `" - "`

Comment: Cool way of going about it with the transformation!

Comment: The solution is absurdly similar in Pyth: `j" - "m|*\M.&Chd6\-c` :-)

Comment: Also The OP adds space to the examples but does not specify them, I've asked for clarification on that.

Comment: @JonathanAllan The bytes `\xef` and `\xa6` are `.o` and `.&` respectively. It's a backwards compatible change where if the high bit is set, it runs it like the old 2 byte commands. I'm writing it this way to make it easier for the reader and because Pyke technically doesn't use a code page anymore and I don't want to have to insert random bytes that don't work

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript, <s>70</s> 63 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to [Luke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63774/luke)*

```
a=>a.replace(/./g,a=>[['Rr','rr','-',' - ']['onp '.search(a)]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TckxDsMgDIXhq7AZpEAOUKWH6IoYLOqQVggjO@31aRp16PC@4X9PfKNmefTdN77TWJeByxWDUK@Yyc5hLtNRYoSbwATyxR8z3kCKwK0bCEooebPoUnIjc1OuFCoXu1qo3IrRjWX/eYaTji@l/w@cu4wP)

Comment: Nice trick with the outer `[]`s!

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>71</s> <s>66</s> 59 bytes

```hs
g 'o'="Rr"
g 'n'="rr"
g 'p'="-"
g ' '=" - "
g _=""
f=(g=<<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TclBCoAgFIThfacYHoG18Aa@S3SBcFEWmYrW@c0sqM3Px8yi0zZZm7OB8IJpiNQUusL4MBTKKhRB4vbIRM3MnWGl@rzr1YER4uoOtJhB1juDmrT4eLz91qDPNP0/yhc)

Oh right, `=<<` is concatMap.

Takes advantage of the fact that `"long"` and `"short"` both have the letter `o`.

Comment: You don't need to pay the 2 bytes for `f=` point-free functions are allowed without assignment

Comment: You can save one whole byte with lambdacase by switching to lambdabot haskell: `(>>=(\case 'o'->"Rr";'n'->"rr";'p'->"-";' '->" - ";_->""))`

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>33</s> <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 21 bytes

```
#εÇн6&'m×™'-)éθ}… - ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f@dzWw@0X9pqpqecenv6oZZG6rubhled21D5qWKagq3B47///xRn5RSUKOfl56QoQZkFiaXEqsgCICQA)

**Explanation**

```
#                       # split input on spaces
 ε             }        # apply to each
  Çн                    # get the character code of the head
    6&                  # AND with 6
      'm×               # repeat "m" this many times
         ™              # title case
          '-)           # wrap in a list with "-"
             éθ         # get the longest string       
                … - ý   # join to string using " - " as separator
```

Saved 3 bytes using the `AND 6` trick from *muddyfish's* [pyke answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140440/47066)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>65</s> 59 bytes

```
s=>s.split` `.map(x=>x<'m'?'Rrrr':x<'q'?'-':'Rr').join` - `
```

```js
let f =

s=>s.split` `.map(x=>x<'m'?'Rrrr':x<'q'?'-':'Rr').join` - `

console.log(f("long long short long short")); // => Rrrr - Rrrr - Rr - Rrrr - Rr
console.log(f("long long long short short short")); // => Rrrr - Rrrr - Rrrr - Rr - Rr - Rr
console.log(f("short short short pause short short short")); // => Rr - Rr - Rr - - - Rr - Rr - Rr
console.log(f("long short short long long pause short short")); // => Rrrr - Rr - Rr - Rrrr - Rrrr - - - Rr - Rr
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>76</s> <s>69</s> 64 bytes

```python
lambda s:' - '.join('Rrrr'[:ord(b[0])&6]or'-'for b in s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY0xC8IwFIR3f8WbfMnQIg4OBf@Ea9shocZGYl54Lw7@@hS6GIjgchzcd3fpk1eK5@KuUwnmZRcDMiB0gP2TfFR4Y2YcB@JF2fE06@NlJsYOHTFY8BGklxR8VlqXxD5mcAoDxQfsIitxri3qww@sAmqt4TZN5i33P61m@HvX1lGXDQ)

**Alternates:**

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>76</s> 69 bytes

```python
lambda s:' - '.join(['Rrrr','-','Rr'][ord(b[1])%3]for b in s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY2xCgIxEER7v2Ib2QS8A7UT/IlrcykSzniRmA2bWPj1UWwMRLCYYWDf7KRnWSkeqjvPNZi7XQzkE8IAON7IR6FwYmbc4fDWxKgV8SKs2mu5PWpHDBZ8hDzmFHwRUtbEPhZwAgPFK3wsr8SljSg3P7AGaL2F@2syj3z50@oef@f6Osr6Ag)

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda s:' - '.join('-Rrrr'['o'in b:8-ord(b[1])%9]for b in s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY0xC8IwFIR3f8Vb5CVDCnXSgn/Cte2QUGMjMS@8xMFfn4qLgQgux8F9dxdfeaVwKPY8Fa8fZtGQBgQF2N3JBYHqwsw4IqELYIajIl6EGftZ7k@zJQYD7yB1KXqXhZQlsgsZrEBP4QYfSStxri3K3Q@sAmqt4TaN@pmuf1rN8PeuraMsGw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings)

1 byte saved thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```
[^lhp ]

l
hrr
h
Rr
p
-
 
 -
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/Oi4no0AhlosrhyujqIgrgyuoiKuAS5dLgUtBV@H//5z8vHSF4oz8ohIoCRYAEwWJpcWpyHIA)

This is different approach than @DomHastings's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140435/72349).

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 81 bytes

```
StringReplace[#,{"long"->"Bzzz -","short"->"Bz -","pause"->"- -"}]~StringDrop~-2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/uKQoMy89KLUgJzE5NVpZp1opJz8vXUnXTsmpqqpKQVdJR6k4I7@oBCIC5hcklhangvi6QG5tbB3ECJei/II6XSO1/wFAXomCQ1o02CQFsG4oCRYAE2AzkOWUYv//BwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>73</s> <s>57</s> <s>47</s> <s>46</s> <s>40</s> 44 bytes

```
f&a{a~=*`s\w+|l;Rr;ong;rr;p\w+;-; ; - `/";"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfz/P00tsTqxzlYroTimXLsmxzqoyDo/L926qMi6AChgrWutYK2gq5Cgr2StVPs/NzEzT6GaizM6PlYhM00hTSHekKv2f3FGflGJAjJZkFhanKqQAzQIQQAA)

+4 bytes due to rule change (must use `Rrrr` instead of any 4 letter variant).

Previous code:

```
{[[split()|["Bzzz"]if[_="long"]else["Bz"]if[_1="short"]else["-"]]&" - "]}
```

Comment: Using `Mmm` and `Mm` is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @ATaco It's said in the question that _"Long sounds should be 4 characters long, and short sounds should be 2 characters long"_.

Comment: ATaco, please note that the criteriums have been further specified in the question.

Answer (score 4):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 39 bytes

**37 bytes code + 2 for `-pa`.**

```perl
$_=join" - ",map/p/?"-":Bz.zz x/l/,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYrPzNPSUFXQUknN7FAv0DfXklXycqpSq@qSqFCP0dfx8Ht//@c/Lx0BTBRnJFfVILE5EJIIckjkVwYIgoFiaXFqVhUYhiAMBZDy7/8gpLM/Lzi/7oFiTkA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 77 bytes

```r
cat(c('Rrrr','Rr','-')[match(scan(,''),c('long','short','pause'))],sep=' - ')
```

Takes input through STDIN, checks whether the input matches `long`, `short` or `pause` and swaps the matches for `Rrrr`, `Rr` or `-` respectively.

This is then printed with `-` padded with spaces as separator, matching the desired output.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by switching from match to %in%: ``scan(,'') %in% c('long','short','pause')``

Comment: @YCR I don't think that'll work. `a %in% b` checks whether entries in the `a` are present in `b`, while `match(a, b)` returns the actual indices of the matches. Since we can assume that the input is valid, using `%in%` would just return a vector of `TRUE`s.

Comment: Arf, true. I have test it with c('long','short','pause').

Comment: That's because when you feed a boolean vector into `[`, it is interpreted as `[which(bool) == TRUE]`, which in your example would be `[c(1,2,3)]`, which in turn happens to give the correct output.

Comment: Instead of `sep=' - '` you can use `s=' - '` for 2 bytes less

Comment: @Rift that doesn't work for me, it just appends ` - ` to the print. Partial matching doesn't really play nice with `...` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>93</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Scepheo!*
*-1 byte thanks to Cyoce!*

Takes a NULL terminated **char or equivalent as an input.

```c
f(char**a){for(;*a;*++a&&printf(" - "))printf(**a&6?**a&1?"Rr":"Rrrr":"-");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY4xD4IwEIV3fsWlJqQtYnRxsCp/gDiYOBmHplBogi0pxYXw22tBHRx0eXff5d3LE2klhF8oLZq@KGHfuUKZVX30EouaW0o5GaSxmFHOaJLwOG6t0k5iBCkgQt4UfPE2m3STobNFuyB2GikibPTBA3euNH4YVRAYIoApHWj4rpzR5fUGh/kMgBqjK7SEF3S1se4HfRm/oOV9V/7PmOF0yfOwjCwKKvGnDWEBbel6q2HNotE/AQ)

Explanations:

```c
f(char**a){
  // While the string at the current position is not NULL
  for(;*a;
    // Advances the pointer to the next string
    // Then if the current string is not NULL, prints a delimiter
    *++a&&printf(" - ")
  )
    /* 
      If the 1st char of the string is not a 'p'
        If the 1st char is not a 'l'
          Prints "Rr"
        Else
          Prints "Rrrr"
      Else:
        Prints "-"
     */
    printf(**a&6?**a&1?"Rr":"Rrrr":"-");
}
```

Comment: I think you can combine `a++,*a` into `*++a` to save two bytes, and take advantage of the vague "sound" definition to use `*a` instead of `"Rrrr"` to save another four bytes.

Comment: Your second suggestion is genius!

Comment: Can you move part of the increment stage of the for-loop to the body instead of being comma-separated?

Comment: This indeed saves a byte. Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 72 bytes

Takes input from stdin, prints to stdout.

```r
cat(sapply(scan(,''),switch,long="vvvv",short="vv",pause="-"),sep=" - ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCcAgDEDRVSQXFeIIGSaI1IJoMLal06f23x78aZZ5BWWR9gbN3AN6H1Gfc@WKbfSD4N4Bah1z/QAUvrQQJNhjEQKXHESzDw)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 88 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set s=%s: = - %
@set s=%s:long=Rrrr%
@set s=%s:short=Rr%
@echo %s:pause=-%
```

Takes input on STDIN. Unfortunately loop overhead costs 26 bytes so this is just boring replacements.

Comment: [Suggested edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43918) to remove all of the `@`s

Comment: @Stephen Yes, I got the notification...

Comment: Nice! Just two things, though: I counted that answer to be 84 bytes long, not 88. Also, OP has replaced `Mmmm` and `Mm` with `Rrrr` and `Rr`, it would be nice to update your answer c:

Comment: Batch as of what platform?  I doubt MS-DOS 6.22 would do what XP does when in enhanced command mode.

Comment: @TOOGAM Yeah, when I say Batch I usually mean Windows NT's CMD.EXE's version.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 31 bytes

```
short|l
Bz
ong
zz
pause
-
 
 -
```

-1 byte thanks to @[fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66323/fergusq)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/OCO/qKQmh8upiis/L52rqoqrILG0OJVLl0uBS0FX4f//HKCwApgAK0ViciGkkOSRSC4MEQWw4VhUYhiAMBZDCwA)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 113 bytes

```
<?$s=[];for($i=1;$i<$argc;$i++){$c=$argv[$i][0];$s[]=($c<'m')?'Rrrr':(($c<'q')?'-':'Rr');}echo implode(' - ',$s);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcmxDsIgGATgV2H4kx9Sm@haQN7BlTA0iIWkFQrqYnx2bImDy@Xuu@RTrUIlnwgUqQ2/xUwhyBOHIGDMk91K17E3WLnPl4Zg9NFwKNpIClbggkzhJeeMA22w7tDjsCEy/nHWRxKWNMero0h6ggcojKtzrXWO96kWH/Pjlw1apPFZ3P/3BQ)

First attempt at code golf, so probably a lot of optimisations available!

Answer (score 2):

## Vim (52 bytes)

`:s/long/Rrrr/ge|s/short/Rr/ge|s/pause/-/ge|s/ / - /g`*enter*

Can probably be made shorter...

Comment: Stringing the commands together like this stops the train if one of them errors IE if there's no pause or something in the given string, the replacements after the one that failed won't work.  You can either split them on separate lines or put an `e` flag at the end

Comment: Corrected the error. I still feel there ought to be some way to speed it up, but the only other way I thought of (after turning "pause" into a dash, `s/[^ -]/r/`, capitalize the first R after every space, trim four-r to two-r) came out longer.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel,  100 bytes

```
=REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"long","- Bzzz"),"short","- Bz"),"pause","- -"),1,2,"")
```

Per examples, Input is `SPACE` separated string, as is output.

Question itself does not mention a `SPACE` requirement, allowing for a slightly shorter **97 byte** solution:

```
=REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"long","-Bzzz"),"short","-Bz"),"pause","--"),1,1,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 32 bytes

```
Í /ò
çl/CRrrr
ço/CRr
çp/-
HòJa-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3Cvgv7hTVyHl@foOwcVFRUBWfkgFpAu0Nfl8ji8yStRV@H//5z8vHQFMFGckV9UgsQEAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com), 145 bytes

```
EXECUTE(STRINGREPLACE('MSGBOX(0,0,STRINGSTRIPWS(====INPUTBOX(0,0),"PAUSE",""),"LONG","Rrrr"),"SHORT","Rr")," "," - "),4))',"=","STRINGREPLACE("))
```

(AutoIt is really bad choice for code golf, tried my best to make it small as possible)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Sed, 50 bytes

Takes input from `stdin`, prints to `stdout`

```
s/l\w*/Rrrr -/g
s/s\w*/Rr -/g
s/p\w*/- -/g
s/ -$//
```

Edit - saved 2 bytes

## Sed, 40 bytes

Copying idea from [Nitrodon's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140542/9174)

```
s/[srtaue]//g
y/lhongp/RRrrr-/
s/ / - /g
```

Edit: saved another 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 37 bytes

```
/ lRnrhR
\""orgrp-""!yi'."?-e"ySNo?@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fIScorygjiCtGSSm/KL2oQFdJSbEyU11PyV43Vaky2C/f3kH///@c/Lx0heKM/KISKAkWABMFiaXFqchyAA)

#### Explanation

This program makes the following substitutions:

- `l`, `h` → `R`
- `o`, `n`, `g` → `r`
- `p` → `-`
- Space → Space
- Everything else → Nothing

```
"longhp "!i.?eyN?"RrrrR- "y' " - "So@

"longhp "    Push this string
!            Immediately move to tape
i            Take input string
.            Duplicate
?ey          Remove all instances of the characters "longhp " from copy
N            Remove the remaining characters from the original, leaving only "longhp "
?"RrrrR- "y  Replace the characters in "longhp " with the corresponding characters in "RrrrR- "
' " - "S     Replace all spaces with " - "
o            Output
@            Terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda s:" - ".join((ord(i[0])&6)*"R"or"-"for i in s.split()).title()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYoxDsIwDAB3XmF5qGykRoiBAYlPsBaGoBZqFOLIMQOvT0Gwstxwd@Xls@Zti4dTS/FxGSPUPUIPGO4qmUhtJBk2Z@52vMYjqmGPVzUQkAw11JLEiTm4eJqIWzHJTpEwab5BndUcSnzWCZlXf@OPX/OJ77st)

Port of my [Pyke answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140440/32686)

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
θ{K;⁄5κ« r*; p=?X┌}}¹" - ”∑ū
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwM0I4JTdCSyUzQiV1MjA0NDUldTAzQkElQUIlMjByKiUzQiUyMHAlM0QlM0ZYJXUyNTBDJTdEJTdEJUI5JTIyJTIwLSUyMCV1MjAxRCV1MjIxMSV1MDE2Qg__,inputs=bG9uZyUyMHNob3J0JTIwc2hvcnQlMjBsb25nJTIwbG9uZyUyMHBhdXNlJTIwc2hvcnQlMjBzaG9ydA__)

fun fact: if it was allowed to delimit with  `-`   or   `-`  it'd be a byte shorter

Answer (score 0):

## [Paradoc](https://github.com/betaveros/paradoc) (v0.2.10), 21 bytes (CP-1252)

```
Wμ‹6&'r\°"-":Ãu}« rTc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsSkzJT/6f@T/83J5HDTvN1NSLYg5tUNJVsjrcXFp7aLVCUUjy//85@XnpCsUZ@UUlUBIsACYKEkuLU5HlAA)

Takes a string on the stack and results in a string on the stack. Prepend `i` to turn into a full program that reads from STDIN.

Uses `&6` like [the Pyke answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140440/19857) and everybody else, but joins the tokens together slightly differently, by adding a `"-"` token after each noise, deleting the last one, and then joining these tokens by spaces. Seems to save a byte over joining by `" - "`.

Explanation:

```
W                     .. Break into words
 μ             }      .. Map over this block:
  ‹                   .. Take the first character
   6&                 .. Binary AND with 6, to get 4, 2, or 0
     'r               .. Character "r"
       \              .. Swap top two of stack
        °             .. Replicate, to get "rrrr", "rr", or ""
         "-"          .. Push string "-"
            :         .. Duplicate on stack
             Ã        .. Compute the max...
              u       .. ... underneath the top of the stack (so, of the
                      .. second and third elements on the stack, i.e. the
                      .. string of "r"s and "-")
                      .. The mappped block ends here; we now have
                      .. something like ["rrrr", "-", "-", "-", "rr", "-"]
                «     .. Take all but the last
                  r   .. Join with spaces (this built-in's name is two
                      .. characters, the first of which is a space)
                   Tc .. Title-case
```

v0.2.11 will support shaving two more bytes by replacing `\°` with `x` and `"-"` with `'-`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
p ARGV[0].chars.map{|c|{p:'-',o:'Rr',g:'rr',' '.to_sym=>' - '}[c.to_sym]}.join
```

The only important parts of the input are `p`, `o`, `g`, and space... ignore the rest.

- `short` becomes `o`
- `long` becomes `og`
- `pause` becomes `p`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DBMcg9LNogVi85I7GoWC83saC6JrmmusBKXVddJ99KPahIXSfdSr0ISKkrqOuV5McXV@ba2qkr6Cqo10YnQwVia/Wy8jPz/v//X5yRX1SikJOflw4hIPyCxNLiVLAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

```ruby
p ARGV[0].split(' ').map{|w|w<'m'?'Rrrr':w<'q'?'-':'Rr'}.join ' - '
```

**This is [Johan Karlsson's JavaScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140447/34307) ported to Ruby.** If you like this answer, you should upvote Johan's answer.

The key idea is to compare the word strings `'short'`, etc. to a single character in order to distinguish between words.

```ruby
| Word  | < 'm' | < 'q' | Output |
|-------|-------|-------|--------|
| short | false | false | 'Rr'   |
| long  | true  | N/A   | 'Rrrr' |
| pause | false | true  | '-'    |
```

Or, in alphabetical order:

- long
- m
- pause
- q
- short

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DBMcg9LNogVq@4ICezRENdQV1TLzexoLqmvKbcRj1X3V49qKioSN0KyCkEcnTVrYAC6rV6WfmZeQrqCroK6v///y/OyC8qUcjJz0uHEBB@QWJpcSpYAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 bytes

```python
' - '.join(['Rrrr','-','Rr'][ord(s[1])%3]for s in input().split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYgxCoAwDEWvkkXSggri7CVcawdBpRVpQlIHT187CsJ/78HnJwdKY9FpKQgdYH9STMbhLCLYYleZBb0j2Yy6wdtm9AcJKMRUx3c2tle@Yq0tLDFlo7ZoIMnwNa@37vD7Xw)